# Game Maker - Create Instance When Health Is 0

Tags: game-maker, instancing

I have five objects: `obj_Boss`, `obj_bossHealth`, `obj_GameOver`, `obj_BtnOK`, and `obj_rec2`.

This is what I want. When `obj_Boss` has no more health, `obj_GameOver` and `obj_BtnOK` will appear.

**This is my first method:**

In `obj_bossHealth`, I have these events:

> Create Event: set var `global.bossHealth to 100`
>
> Draw Event: draw_healthbar

In `obj_Boss`, I have these events:

> Collision with `obj_rec2`: set var `global.bossHealth relative to -1.5`; destroy the instance (other)
>
> No More Health: create instance of `obj_GameOver`; create instance of `obj_BtnOK`

**This is my second method:**

In `obj_bossHealth`, I have these events:

> Create Event: set var `global.bossHealth to 100`
>
> Draw Event: draw_healthbar
>
> Step Event: if `global.bossHealth is equal to 0` then create instance of `obj_GameOver` and create instance of `obj_BtnOK`

In `obj_Boss`, I have these events:

> Collision with `obj_rec2`: set var `global.bossHealth relative to -1.5`; destroy the instance (other)

**The result of both methods:**

`obj_GameOver` and `obj_BtnOK` won't appear. How can I fix this? Please explain your answer. Thanks.

I add some images: [method1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hu6cc4l3qgu06en/Untitled-1.jpg?dl=0) [method2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g94b8i6sbrcy6pl/Untitled-2.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: I heavily encourage the act of integrating all these things into one boss object. The health of the boss can just be stored as one variable and you can draw the health bar with the boss object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `obj_GameOver` and `obj_BtnOK` won't appear is because you are checking the wrong variable. The *No More Health Event* is triggered by checking for the value of variable [`health`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/variables/health.html). From the [YoYo Documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/000_using%20gamemaker/events/other%20event.html):

> **No More Health**
>
> GameMaker: Studio has a built-in health system, which, like Lives
>   above, is basically a global scope variable that is created for you at
>   the start of a game. There are actions to set and change the health
>   variable as well as to draw a health-bar, with code available to
>   change them too should you prefer to use GML. This event is triggered
>   whenever the health becomes less than or equal to 0. It is typically
>   used to reduce the number of lives or to restart the game or room.

Since in the first method you are working with the variable `global.bossHealth`, which was defined by *you*, instead of `health`, a *built-in* variable modeled around the GM:S framework functionalities, there's absolutely no chance your *No More Health Event*s will be triggered. If you set `global.bossHealth` to 0 or less, `health` will still be 100 or somewhat else.

Being the `health` variable in unique wherever you read/write it from, that's why I encourage your second method.

#### It's just a math matter

The reason your buttons won't appear is just a mathematical issue: if your `bossHealth` starts from 100 and you subtract 1.5 per hit, we'll get to the point where the `obj_Boss` has been hit 66 times. Then, the health amount the Boss lost is:

> 66 [hits] * 1.5 [damage per hit] = 99 [damage]

At this point, its health will be:

> 100 [health] - 99 [damage] = 1 [health]

And here comes the trouble: if the Boss is hit again, his health will be:

> 1 - 1.5 = -0.5

But since you are checking for `global.bosHealth` to be equal to 0, this condition will never evaluate to true.

#### The solution

This is *VERY* simple: just edit your condition for `global.bossHealth` value: don't just check if it is equal to zero, but **less than or equal to**.

In the *Step Event* of object `obj_bossHealth`, your code would look as follows:

```
// Step event - Check health
if (global.bossHealth <= 0)
{
    instance_create(x1,y1,obj_GameOver);
    instance_create(x2,y2,obj_BtnOK);
}
```

Here, `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, and `y2` are meant to be set to the right values for your objects.

Comment: It's working. Yes, it's very simple. But, I didn't realize it before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation (press F1 when GM:S is open) if something doesn't look clear to you, I still find it very helpful. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked in GameMaker Studio before but just from looking at your screenshot it appears that when obj_rec2 collides with obj_Boss it is literally setting bossHealth to -1.5, so that after the collision it bossHealth = -1.5. Therefore bossHealth is never reaching 0 to create instances of obj_BtnOK and obj_GameOver

Comment: No, I set it to `relative`. Which means `bossHealth` -= 1.5. When `obj_Boss` collides, `bossHealth` is reduced by 1.5